# Laravel access to relation in WHEN

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Hello guys i need to implement filtering result for Document model. My document model have relation with Customer and i need to filter that results with searching multiple columns in customer relation (name and address). I try with traditional way `$document->customerRelation->name`,  `customer.name` and isn't working.

So i have HTML table with prited documents and there is also printed customer name and customer address. When i type in text box some keywords like (jon or test) i need to filter that columns.

| Document | Customer | Address | Document Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00213 | Jon | Test | Inovice |
| 00214 | Thomas | Test | Proforma |
| 00215 | Agly | Test | Guaranty |
| 00216 | Adams | Test | User manual |

**Here is code**

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
       $documents = 
            Document::when(
                    $request->has('document_tip_id'), function ($q) use ($request) {
                        return $q->where('document_tip_id', $request->query('document_tip_id'));
                    }) // this working 


       // Here i need to filter by relation (customer.name or address and other columns)


         ->when(
            $request->has('keywords'), function ($q) use ($request) {
              return $q->where('customer.name', '%'.$request->query('customer') . '%');
           })
                
                ->with('products')
                ->with('customer')
                ->orderBy('created_at');
    
            $documents = $documents->paginate(20)->withQueryString();
    
            dd($documents);
    
            return ....
    }
```

**Dump**

```
Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator {#408 ▼ // app/Http/Controllers/Order/BuyerController.php:38
  #items: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#346 ▼
    #items: array:20 [▼
      0 => App\Models\Document {#321 ▼
        #connection: "mysql"
        #table: "dokument"
        #primaryKey: "id"
        #keyType: "int"
        #observables: []
        #relations: array:2 [▼
          "product" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#343 ▶}
          "customer" => App\Models\Customer {#432 ▼
            #connection: "mysql"
            #table: "customer"
            #primaryKey: "id"
            #keyType: "int"
            +incrementing: true
            #with: []
            #withCount: []
            +preventsLazyLoading: false
            #perPage: 15
            +exists: true
            +wasRecentlyCreated: false
            #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
            #attributes: array:28 [▼
              "id" => 975
              "code" => "123"
              "name" => "Jon Don"
              "address" => "Test address"
              "created_at" => "2020-11-05 21:55:46"
              "updated_at" => "2020-11-05 21:55:46"
              "deleted_at" => null
            ]
```

**Model**

```
// Customer.php
  public function customer()
  {
     return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'subjekat_id');
  }
```

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'customer.name'
> in 'where clause'

Comment: Can you add migration file of documents

Comment: You can see in dump structure. Migration is not important i have only two column in customer table what i need to search `name(varchar)` and `address(varchar)`. Also in dump you can see primary

Comment: How come your `Customer` model has a `public function customer(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo` relationship? Please share your relevant migration files ('documents', 'customers', 'products'). As it currently stands, we don't know how all these *'objects'* are related. Nonetheless, I think a combination of Eloquent queries and Query Builder `->join(...)` would do the trick.

Comment: Its already printed with relation. You can see model method on bottom. Also migration show full table structure. For this problem in dump is all showed what is important for this problem. In this case join is not requered becouse relation already works. By the way i slove problem and post it. Thanks for your time bro. By

Comment: [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is sloved using whereReklation

```
     ->when(
          $request->has('keywords'),
               function ($q) use ($request) {
                  return $q->whereRelation('customer', 'name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->query('keywords') . '%');
})
```